# Breaking out of a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm trying to break out of a for loop from inside an if statement.
The break works, and doesn't continue iterations, but my alert gets posted twice.  Why is this happening?

```
sequence = 0;
keepGoing = true;

for (var p = 0; p < maxValue; p++) {
    if (dataRecord[p].number <= sequence) {
        alert("Something is not right! Try again");
        keepGoing = false;
        break;
    }
    else {
        sequence = dataRecord[p].number;
        alert("This one is ok!");
    }
}

if (keepGoing) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Which `alert` appears twice?

Comment: "Something is not right" alerts twice?  Are you sure your code isn't being executed twice?

Comment: What happens when you step through it? Don't forget about the `debugger` keyword.

Comment: The loop by it self will not fire the "Something is not right!" alert twice (see http://jsfiddle.net/rolfv1/Cv8Ac/1/), so something else in your script causes that behaviour.

Comment: The alert inside the 'if'. It should only get to show once.

Comment: MaxValue is the length of dataRecord array. debugger keyword??? let me run my eyes over the full code...

Answer (score 0):

That means the for loop is being run twice.